# Joomla 2.5 home page redirect issue

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to set `joomla` site to redirect visiting users to registration page if my `cookie` is not set.
I've put below code in top of the (after imports) `template` `index.php` file.

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["abc"])){   
    $app = &JFactory::getApplication();    
    $link = "index.php?option=com_users&view=registration";
    $app->redirect($link);
   exit();
}
```

URL is redirect but it is going in loop. so page not loading correctly. 
This is fire bug screen shot 
[image]

How to omit this loop ?
Thanks.

Comment: try with $app->redirect(JURI::root().$link);

Comment: Yes I did already but same results.

Comment: try with simple redirect above this code if success then check your conditions. i think your code excuting may times and not redirecting properly. and also check your code is not running on resigration page

Comment: nop. I can't understand why is that loop running?

Comment: Just on a side note, please (if you haven't already) commit to the [Joomla Answers Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla?referrer=Ph_HGDW6OiEqU7r0cS-muA2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem because of your code. You put your code on top of page... your redirection to registration page is correctly but when page goes to registration page.. at that time this code also check because it is on top of index file.. so again redirect on registration page.

So, loop continue redirecting...then i think issue create.

Put condition on your code with cookies like below,

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["abc"]) && empty($_COOKIE['is_redirected']) && (new condition)){
```

- new condition: above replace new condition with `check your page is not login or register what you want.`

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the page you are redirecting to runs the piece of code you have mentioned in your question.

If so, you can use a placeholder cookie.

Here is how:

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["abc"]) && empty($_COOKIE['is_redirected'])){   
    $app = &JFactory::getApplication();    
    $link = "index.php?option=com_users&view=registration";
    setcookie("is_redirected", "true", time()+3600); // this will make sure that only one redirection happens
    $app->redirect($link);
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. same thing happen. loop is running.

Comment: Thanks. dude. Seems it works. I'll check and accept the answer :D

Comment: Welcome, but make sure that if you clear cookie abc thru a PHP code do enable redirection, do not forget to remove cookie is_redirected too

Answer (score 1):

cause template index.php running on all pages and also on registration page so you need to set cookie values before redirect. so it will be set on register page and you not redirect again

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["abc"])){   
        $app = &JFactory::getApplication();    
        $link = "index.php?option=com_users&view=registration";
        setcookie("abc", "true", time()+3600);
        $app->redirect($link);
       exit();
    }
```